# Can not removeClass in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

The loading class is added but it doesn't removed. How to fix this ?

```
$(".phones").addClass("loading");
    that = this
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(that).removeClass('loading');
    }, 3000);
```

Comment: What context is this code being run in?  What is `this` supposed to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
var phones = $(".phones").addClass("loading");
setTimeout(function() {
    phones.removeClass('loading');
}, 3000);
```

I'm not sure why you're worried about scope, though.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to do:

```
$(".phones").addClass("loading");
setTimeout(function() {
    $(".phones").removeClass('loading');
}, 3000);
```

`that` = `this`, which refers to the `window` object if there is no smaller enclosing scope.

Answer (score 0):

that=this has nothing to do with $(".phones") as your indentation hints at.

```
var phones = $(".phones").addClass("loading");
setTimeout(function() {
    phones.removeClass('loading');
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are adding the class to a group of elements defined by the class selector `.phones` but your removing it from a single element defined by the saved item `that`.  It seems like you want to add and remove from the same group.  To do this just use the same queries

```
$(".phones").addClass("loading");    
setTimeout(function() {
  $(".phones").removeClass('loading');
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score -1):

Change `that = this` to `that = $(this);`, Not tested but believe this would help

Comment: It would just become `$($(this))` that way; it does not really add anything.